# How are these two forms of the 2nd derivative of a parametric equation equivalent?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

I was reading about parametric equations and their derivatives, when I came across the following formula for parametric equations $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$

$$ \frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)= \frac{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)}{\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}}$$

I wanted to see where this formula came from, and so I tried to derive it, and ended up with the following:
$$\frac{\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}  \frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2} - \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2}}{\left( \frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt} \right)^3 }$$

After this, I got stuck. I am pretty certain that my equation is correct, however I do not know how the two forms are equivalent. If someone could help derive the top equation from the bottom one, I would really appreciate it. Please be as specific as possible and justify each step, thank you :)

Edit: Here is my derivation of the bottom equation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUm2f.jpg
I had a small typo all the way down, instead of $dt$ it should be $dt^2$.

Comment: Is $(\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}x)^3$ a typo?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I will edit it right now

Comment: I did not check everything, but are you sure both expressions are correct? It's easy to show that $(x'y'' - y'x'')/(x')^3 = (y'/x')'/x'$, but I don't see how that could be generally equivalent to $y''/x'$

Comment: @Buster it may be too late to edit it, but remember that you can use $\LaTeX$ macros in comments the same way as in questions and answers. It makes math expressions much more readable

Comment: I wholeheartedly apologize, this post is a bit of trainwreck. Yes, in the top expression I mistyped dy/dx to dy/dt. I will also upload my derivation

Comment: @VictorSouza had another typo.  again, really sorry. I triple checked: everything is correct now.

Comment: Hand waving function invertibility questions away, ${dy\over dx} = {dy\over dt} \left({dx\over dt}\right)^{-1}$, so it seems both expressions are equivalent indeed. If you want, I can post a proper answer later, but I believe you can get the gist

Comment: @VictorSouza are you saying to substitute $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for $\frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx}$ in my equation, or are you explaining the derivation of the first derivative?

Comment: @VictorSouza in both cases, I would really appreciate if you could post the full derivation. I keep getting mixed up in the algebra :(

Comment: I suspect that if you substitute ${dy\over dx}$ for ${dy\over dt}{dt\over dx}$ in the first expression and expand the derivative w.r.t. $t$ you will arrive at the second expression. If it's true, you can work your way backwards to really convince yourself that they're equivalent

Comment: Of course, I meant the other way around: substitute ${dy\over dt}{dt\over dx}$ for ${dy\over dx}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple to show that both expressions are equivalent. For convenience, I'll use prime notation for derivatives w.r.t. $t$ and quotient notation for all others.

Start with
$$
{x'y'' - x''y'\over (x')^3} = {1\over x'}{x'y'' - x''y'\over (x')^2} = {1\over x'} \left({y'\over x'}\right)'
$$
by the quotient rule.

To finish it off, we note informally that
$$
{y'\over x'} = {\mathrm dy\over\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dt\over \mathrm dx} = {\mathrm dy\over\mathrm dx},
$$
so
$$
{1\over x'} \left({y'\over x'}\right)' = {1\over x'}\left({\mathrm dy\over\mathrm dx}\right)'
$$
QED.

---

To give ourselves some peace of mind that the derivative of $t$ w.r.t. $x$ does indeed equals $1/x'$, suppose that it exists some function $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}(x)=t$ for all $x$. Taking the derivative of both sides w.r.t. $t$, we have
$$
{\mathrm d\over\mathrm dx}f^{-1}(x)x' = 1
$$
by the chain rule, so
$$
{\mathrm d\over\mathrm dx}f^{-1}(x) = {1\over x'}.
$$

Since $f^{-1}(x)=t$ by assumption, we have
$$
{\mathrm dt\over\mathrm dx} = {1\over x'}.
$$